# How to write regex to validate dates?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working in JavaScript and I need to figure out how to determine a valid date using regular expressions.

The matches will be:

```
dd-mm-yyyy
dd-mm-yy
```

Also, no leading zeros should be accepted like:

```
9-8-2010
10-6-99
```

How can I write a regular expression to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came up with this:

```
function isValidDate(inputDate){

    var myRegex = /^(\d{1,2})([\-\/])(\d{1,2})\2(\d{4}|\d{2})$/;
    var match = myRegex.exec(inputDate);

    if (match != null) {
        var auxDay = match[1];
        var auxMonth = match[3] - 1;
        var auxYear = match[4];
        auxYear = auxYear.length < 3 ? (auxYear < 70 ? '20' + auxYear : '19' + auxYear) : auxYear;
        var testingDate = new Date(auxYear,auxMonth,auxDay);
        return ((auxDay == testingDate.getDate()) && (auxMonth == testingDate.getMonth()) && (auxYear == testingDate.getFullYear()));
    } else return false;
}
```

Works for `dd-mm-yyyy`, `dd-mm-yy`, `d-m-yyyy` and `d-m-yy`, using `-` or `/` as separators

Based on [This script](http://www.codetoad.com/javascript_IsValidDate.asp)

Answer (score 4):

You'd better do a split on `-` and test all elements. But if you really want to use a regex you can try this one :

```
/^(?:(?:31-(?:(?:0?[13578])|(1[02]))-(19|20)?\d\d)|(?:(?:29|30)-(?:(?:0?[13-9])|(?:1[0-2]))-(?:19|20)?\d\d)|(?:29-0?2-(?:19|20)(?:(?:[02468][048])|(?:[13579][26])))|(?:(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1\d)|(?:2[0-8]))-(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))-(?:19|20)?\d\d))$/
```

Explanation:

```
^            # start of line
 (?:         # group without capture
             # that match 31st of month 1,3,5,7,8,10,12
   (?:       # group without capture
     31      # number 31
     -       # dash
     (?:     # group without capture
       (?:   # group without capture
         0?  # number 0 optionnal
         [13578] # one digit either 1,3,5,7 or 8
       )     # end group
       |     # alternative
       (1[02]) # 1 followed by 0,1 or 2
     )       # end group
     -       # dash
     (19|20)? #numbers 19 or 20 optionnal
     \d\d    # 2 digits from 00 to 99 
   )         # end group
|
   (?:(?:29|30)-(?:(?:0?[13-9])|(?:1[0-2]))-(?:19|20)?\d\d)
|
   (?:29-0?2-(?:19|20)(?:(?:[02468][048])|(?:[13579][26])))
|
   (?:(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1\d)|(?:2[0-8]))-(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))-(?:19|20)?\d\d)
 )
$
```

I've explained the first part, leaving the rest as an exercise.

This match one invalid date : `29-02-1900` but is correct for any date between `01-01-1900` and `31-12-2099`

Answer (score 1):

To validate yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM simplistically (24 hr time):

```
var dateFormat=/^20\d{2}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-[0-3]\d\s([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d$/;
var myDate="2017-12-31"; 
if ( myDate.match(dateFormat)){
    console.log('matches');
};
```

Changing the first term ( 20\d{2} ) to \d{4} will allow any 4-digit year, including 0000 and 9999. Also, this regex forces leading zeroes for month, day, hours, and minutes.

This regex checks for:

- the year to be 20xx; change to your preference.
- leading zeroes for month, day, hours, and minutes

This regex doesn't check for:

- Month / day accuracy (it will allow Feb 30 and June 31, for example)
- Leap years
- AM or PM (it's for 24-hour time)

Answer (score 0):

Step-by-step solution:

```
function mDateVerify(date) {
    function isLeap(y) {
        return (y % 400 === 0 || y % 100 !== 0) && (y % 4 === 0);
    }
    date = date.match(/^(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})-(\d+)$/);
    if (date === null) {
        return false; // if match failed
    }
    var year = parseInt(date[3], 10),
        month = parseInt(date[2], 10),
        day = parseInt(date[1], 10);
    if (month > 12) {
        return false;
    }
    if (month === 2) { // February
        if (isLeap(year)) {
            if (day > 29) {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            if (day > 28) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    if ((month < 8 && month % 2 === 0) || (month >= 8 && month % 2 === 1)) {
        if (day > 30) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (day > 31) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got some result to validate for mm/dd/yyyy format

```
^(((0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])|(0[13-9]|1[0-2])/(29|30)|(0[13578]|1[02])/31)/(?!0000)[0-9]{4}|02/29/([0-9]{2}(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])00))$
```

Answer (score 0):

This variation validates "ddmmyy" without delimiters.

```
^(?:(?:(?:0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])|(?:29|30)(?:0[13-9]|1[0-2])|31(?:0[13578]|1[02]))\d{2}|2902((?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|00))$
```

(was tested on debuggex).
... and it validates leap years by two digits in this century anyway.

Answer (score -2):

How about this?

```
[1-9]{1,2}[-./][1-12]{1}[-./](19|20)[1-99]{1}
```

I have not tested this. And this does not validate leap years

Comment: this will allow invalid dates, like 31-02-2010