# Best way to check dates (DateTime vs regex)

Tags: php, regex, date, datetime

Currently, what's is the best to way to check dates and why?

In a "modern way" using DateTime?

```
$date="2014-02-04";
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $date);

return $dt !== false && !array_sum($dt->getLastErrors());
```

Or using regex?

```
$date="2014-02-04";

return (preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/",$date));
```

Do you have any other comments or suggestions?

Comment: It is very cumbersome to code the date logic into a regex, while DateTime has already provide everything for you.

Comment: Note that a regex way to check date is more complicated than what you wrote since your pattern also validates this kind of date: `2014-02-31`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yes, I wrote a simple example just to demonstrate the situation.

Answer (score 2):

with `RegEx` you can check only correct format of date string.

```
$date="2014-02-04";

return (preg_match("/^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$/", $date));
```

But if you want to check correct date so use [checkdate](https://www.php.net/checkdate) PHP function

```
$arr = explode("-", $date);
if ( checkdate((int)$arr[1], (int)$arr[2], (int)$arr[0]) ) {
    echo "Correct date";
} else {
    echo "Incorrect date";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is the one that best suits your needs.

If you think a 40 characters long regexp is better than a specialized function that can do the same job more efficiently and with more readable code, then by all means use a regexp.

Answer (score 1):

Using DateTime is certainly the right way.

But if you really want a regex, have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3873172/372239).

Answer (score 1):

With regex we can only check format of the string but using the DateTime functions we can check the date is valid or not. So I prefer to use Datetime function to check date.

Answer (score 0):

## Definitely the first way.

Don't use regex for parsing dates or HTML.

---

### Some basic reasons:

- Regex is pretty slow when used on non-trivial patterns.
- Try to avoid regex if there is a ready-made tailored `function or classes` on PHP.

Comment: I agree, but there isn't a complete answer