# date time of regular expression

Tags: regex

I write a regular expression to determine the date time.(the assumption are every month has `31` days and the year only contain `1900` to `2099`)

```
^(((((0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.\\](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))|((0?[1-9]|(1|2)[0-9]|3[01])[- /.\\](0?[1-9]|[1][012])))([- /.\\](19|20)\d{2})))$
```

the format of date time are:

```
dd-mm-yyyy
mm-dd-yyyy
0m-0d-yyyy
0d-0m-yyyy
m-d-yyyy
d-m-yyyy
```

everything works fine except one thing; if the date time like `32-10-2010`, in my thought it should not be recognized, but in regex tester `2-10-2010` has been recognized. I wonder if there is any way to modify the regular expression to prevent it.

Comment: Why not use SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: @m0skit0 Probably not a java question

Comment: What language do you use with regex? PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing the `/` at the end, your RegEx is working for me. Here's a simple Sublime Text RegEx Find/Replace:

[image]

Here is the adjusted regex:

```
^(((((0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.\\](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))|((0?[1-9]|(1|2)[0-9]|3[01])[- /.\\](0?[1-9]|[1][012])))([- /.\\](19|20)\d{2})))$
```

**But a better solution** would be to use the languages native date functionality. I can't think of a language that doesn't have inbuilt methods for these sorts of things.

For example, using JavaScript's `Date` object, or some such...

Comment: And what about `31-02-2012`? Is this date also correct? I don't think so :)

Comment: So better need to use special functions for it, not a RegEx

Comment: Just noticed it was February! Hmm, it would definitely need a larger regex, but I wouldn't say it couldn't be done... But it would be a ball ache.

Comment: But I think it's unreal to write such pattern ) And it would be much slower that specific functions

Comment: I agree. I will edit my answer so that "But a better solution" is in bold. :-p

Answer (score 0):

The **valid** date format pattern in your case is:

```
/^\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}$/
```

With RegEx you can validate only **format** of date, not a **correct** date, because it's a bad practice! Months can be with different days, so good luck to write pattern that will be consider it.

If You want to validate is date correct, use other build-in functions in your language. For example [checkdate](https://www.php.net/checkdate) for PHP or etc.

Comment: this matches 32-10-2010 also, which is what the op wants to avoid.

Comment: Read my answer to the end, please. I said that it's a bad idea to **validate date** with RegEx. Better use a special function, not a RegEx patterns for it.

Comment: I did read your answer to the end. If you were to read my answer, you would note that I've also suggested using native methods for validation. But you don't say that it is 'bad practise', you imply that it simply can't be done. In my opinion, the op has actually done a pretty good job of making it work. At the end of the day, a 'correct date' **can** be validated using regex...

Comment: Ok, I add `bad practise` to my answer. Also read my comment to the your answer, please )

Comment: Have done. Like I said, I agree that validation should be done with a method, especially one that is native to the language, but I can see the usefulness of a quick regex to assert some basic principles. :-)

Comment: `some basic principles` for RegEx in this case is to check the date format only, not a count of valid days in month etc.

Comment: @Victor I agree.sometime Prof has weird request :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
^((3[01]|0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9])-(1[012]|0?[1-9])|((1[012]|0?[1-9])-(3[01]|0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9])))-(19|20)[0-9][0-9]$
```

Answer (score 0):

I've already given such an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3873172/372239).

This match one invalid date : 29-02-1900 but is correct for any date between 01-01-1900 and 31-12-2099