# how can I validate a date of birth using Regular Expression (RegExp), in a react form?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

```
const dateRegex = new RegExp('/^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d+$/')
        if (!formData.dob || !dateRegex.test(formData.dob)) {
            formErrors.dob = "date of birth is required"
        }
```

The RegExp I am using for the date of birth isn't working. Can someone help me with this, please?

[image: regex]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript date regex DD/MM/YYYY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465375/javascript-date-regex-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this RegEx

```
^(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])([\/.-])(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\1(?:19|20)\d\d$
```

You can read more about this regex in this post:
[Date of birth validation by using regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22160079/date-of-birth-validation-by-using-regular-expression)

Checkout Coenwulf's answer

Comment: I tried it as well as the reference you suggested, but they both didn't work. I guess my situation requires a different type of approach. I am currently using Next js & TypeScript.