# Validate February as part of date validation using regexp

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to validate a date using regexp (it's for homework on regexp - yes I know there are better ways doing this in Java using the API)

So far I managed the following expression:

```
(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[012])/((18|19|20|21)\\d\\d)
```

I would like to add a check for February, i.e. cannot have 30 and 31 in the days is 2 is in the month 
(let's assume no leap year check)

How can I add this check into my expression?

Comment: Just don't use regex.

Comment: By not using an unmaintainable regex, and instead writing some simple code.

Comment: It's for homework and I need to do it using regexp

Comment: What are you doing that makes java's built in date parsing not good enough?

Comment: just use Calendar class

Comment: Why `)` is used in your regexp?

Comment: I think whole expression is inside `(` and `)` and he copied the inside code here. It is a mistake. @nikpon

Comment: `(0[1-9]|[12][0-9])/2/((18|19|20|21)\\d\\d)` why this is not answer to your question? Sorry! May be I didn't understand your question if it is not answer.

Comment: Bacuse I want to add a check in case it is 2 not hardcode 2

Comment: first you should add example of a valid date I believe...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to match valid dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224/regular-expression-to-match-valid-dates)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/3873172/372239

Answer (score 2):

For the format **dd/mm/yyyy**

```
^(?:(?:[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/0?2|(?:30|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/(?:0?[469]|11)|(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))/[0-9]{4}$
```

The only problem with this regex is, that it will match the 29th of february of every year.

---

This regular expression consists of:

```
(?:[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/0?2
```

This part trys to match the correct day and month if the month is february. (From 1st to 29th of february)

---

If the month is not february try to match:

```
(?:30|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/(?:0?[469]|11)
```

This part trys to match every month that has 30 days. (it's the month 4,6,9 and 11) (From 1st to 30th day of month).

---

If the month also is not April, June, September, or November

```
(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/(?:0?[13578]|1[02])
```

This part trys to match the month (1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10 and 12)

---

The last part: `[0-9]{4}` matches the year. (Every 4-digit number)

---

If you want the regex to match only till 28th of february use:

```
^(?:(?:1[0-9]|2[0-8]|0?[1-9])/0?2|(?:30|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/(?:0?[469]|11)|(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))/[0-9]{4}$
```

---

If you want the regex to match only till 28th of february dd/mm/yyyy with required leading zero if lower than 2 digits: (you just have to replace all 0? with 0)

```
^(?:(?:1[0-9]|2[0-8]|0[1-9])/02|(?:30|[12][0-9]|0[1-9])/(?:0[469]|11)|(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9])/(?:0[13578]|1[02]))/[0-9]{4}$
```

Comment: I would use `[1-9][0-9]*` for the year - can't see any reason why we should restrict it beyond that

Comment: This is better! Please can you walk me through the explanation?

Comment: How can I change this to accept only 28 days in Feb please and let's assume no check for leap year?

Comment: Thanks! new problem: it doesn't follow the format I expect: dd/mm/yyyy, it accepts 1/9/2014 for example

Answer (score 0):

Nasty regex.

```
    String days30 = "(0{0,1}[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)";
    String days31 = "(0{0,1}[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])";
    String days28 = "(0{0,1}[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])";
    String month30 = "(0{0,1}(4|6|9)|11)";
    String month31 = "(0{0,1}(1|3|5|7|8)|1(0|2))";
    String years = "(17|18|19|20)\\d\\d";
    String dateExpr = "((" + days30 + "/" + month30 + ")|(" + days31 + "/" + month31 + ")|(" + days28 + "/02))/" + years;
```

Updated

Do not use regular expressions to validate dates! That question was a typical nonsense homework but I accepted the challenge.

Note also, that this regular expression is not the best you could come up with, but it is clear and simple.

Considering the compile and parse time, it is however much faster than the look ahead ones.

Comment: Days = 00 would pass.  I think you meant `days28` instead of `days24`. Also, you need an extra set of parens to `years` applies to all month/day options and not just the last.

Comment: Fixed it... the next morning.

Comment: Doesn't pass for 05/09/1999

Comment: Doesn't match `29/02/2000` and `{0,1}` can be written `?`

Comment: @M42 No leap years, but at least the regexp is that simple my daughter could add the 29.