# Regular expression for ddmmyyyy date including validation for leap year

Tags: regex, angularjs, validation

How can we check the date in ddmmyyyy format (including leap year validation) using regular expression? What would be the regular expression...?

Comment: Did you try something already?

Comment: **Can you do this without regular expression?** It would be a mess to maintain.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility, that regex may not be the right solution to that problem?

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3873172/372239

Comment: I'm trying this in angularJS, I've to write another directive for this validation

Comment: @M42 I've already searched over google about validation but I want validation for date in ddmmyyyy format. Can you show me the duplicated one I haven't found my answer in the link provided by you

Comment: The answer I gave does exactly ddmmyyyy, but @M42's link is a very similar approach and it shouldn't be too hard for anyone to adapt it and remove the separator. You are sounding very "give me ze code" and "do my work for me" when insisting in multiple comments that you only want something that works for exactly ddmmyyyy.

Comment: @funkwurm I know the stackoverflow rules man however I've tried similar approaches by removing seperators (-, ., /) but I was unable to find the correct one. Anyway thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Dude, you asked the question I've been working on for a couple of weeks. I invite those commenting to give a date that breaks this. Now note that this works for the years **1000-9999**, is **[Proleptic Gregorian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar)** and assumes that we won't change how leap-years work until the year 9999 ;)

```
^(?:(?:(?:0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])|(?:29|30)(?:0[13-9]|1[0-2])|31(?:0[13578]|1[02]))[1-9]\d{3}|2902(?:[1-9]\d(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:[2468][048]|[13579][26])00))$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/-YBLkWQt3OmIJZxS)

Comment: To be precise, your regex works for year 1000-9999

Comment: Excellent and its working..

Comment: Fails for October 10/29 and 10/30 of each year. So there's that.

Comment: @MichaelPaulukonis [works perfectly fine](https://regex101.com/r/qyko17/1)? Beware that this is `ddmmyyyy` not `mmddyyyy` as your 10/29 and 10/30 are.

Answer (score 0):

Regex for `dd/MM/yyyy` even for leap year:

```
pattern="(^(((0[1-9]|[12][0-8])[\/](0[1-9]|1[012]))|((29|30|31)[\/](0[13578]|1[02]))|((29|30)[\/](0[4,6,9]|11)))[\/](19|[2-9][0-9])\d\d$)|(^29[\/]02[\/](19|[2-9][0-9])(00|04|08|12|16|20|24|28|32|36|40|44|48|52|56|60|64|68|72|76|80|84|88|92|96)$)"
```

Or simple

```
pattern= "^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/((19|20)\\d\\d)$"
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer however I want date validation for ddmmyyyy not dd/MM/yyyy format

Comment: pattern= "^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(0?[1-9]|1[012])((19|20)\\d\\d)$";

Comment: @user3337073: Please edit it in your post.

Comment: it doesnot validate the leap year , 30 or 31 days of a month