# JSON Schema to check date of YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: java, json, date, jsonschema

Could someone tell me JSON Schema Validation for accepting date of `YYYY-MM-DD` format alone?

My sample JSON:

```
{"data1" : "foo", "date" :"2016-11-24"}
```

Comment: Please add your sample JSON

Comment: Have updated it.

Answer (score 50):

JSON Schema already have defined format for date, time, datetime, email, hostname, IP address. You can prefer this easier and recommended method rather than writing your own regex.

```
"date": {
  "type": "string",
  "format": "date"
}
```

Date and time format names are derived from RFC 3339, section 5.6 [RFC3339].

Reference: http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.7.3

Comment: As per the JSON specification, it seems that these formats are not mandatory. Is this correct? https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string.html#format

Comment: @リカルド I think this note is unambiguous: *"JSON Schema implementations are not required to implement this part of the specification, and many of them do not."*

Comment: The documentation states that [format does not affect validation](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string.html#dates-and-times:~:text=By%20default%2C%20format%20is%20just%20an%20annotation%20and%20does%20not%20effect%20validation).

Comment: It has based on the json schema validator you use. I mostly use `ajv` which considers the format field and will validate. You may need to check with the validator you using. @TroyWeber

Comment: @RamBabu Thank you for clarifying. If you isn't too late to update your response to include that _some_ json-schema validators allow you to validate on this optional format, I recommend doing so since this is the highest voted answer, just for the sake of clarity. Otherwise, I'm glad to hear that `ajv` supports this behavior.

Answer (score 5):

add regex to json schema
in schema use the following.

```
{
   "type": "string",
   "pattern": "^\d{4}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$"
}
```

Comment: Using this regex will accept 30 February too.. thats my issue

Comment: oh ok you just pointed out for format.. but for validity you can refer to following link.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224/regular-expression-to-match-valid-dates/8768241#8768241

Comment: Just tried this. Get an error: ValueError: Invalid \escape

Comment: double escape `\\d`

Comment: `\d` is not part of the [supported subset](http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/regular_expressions.html) of regex features.

Comment: Correct Schema:   `^(?:\d{4})-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$`

Answer (score 4):

Use [built-in support](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string.html#dates-and-times) for date validation:

```
{"type": "string", "format": "date"}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Isn't it the same solution as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48664720/2227743)?

Comment: Please note that the documentation also states [that the "format" is more of an annotation](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string.html#dates-and-times:~:text=By%20default%2C%20format%20is%20just%20an%20annotation%20and%20does%20not%20effect%20validation) and doesn't trigger any validation without 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Use below solution ... it should work good for all dates in YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY/MM/DD format. It validated leap year and restricts dates in month of Feb as well.

```
{
   "type": "string",
   "pattern": "(((19|20)([2468][048]|[13579][26]|0[48])|2000)[/-]02[/-]29|((19|20)[0-9]{2}[/-](0[469]|11)[/-](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)|(19|20)[0-9]{2}[/-](0[13578]|1[02])[/-](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])|(19|20)[0-9]{2}[/-]02[/-](0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])))"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably easier to use [seconds since EPOCH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) or the [Julian date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day):

```
{"type":"number"}
```

instead of a [regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28022901/402322) for an [ISO 8601 time stamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations):

```
{"type":"string","pattern":"^(?:[1-9][0-9]{3}-(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])|(?:0[13-9]|1[0-2])-(?:29|30)|(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31)|(?:[1-9][0-9](?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:[2468][048]|[13579][26])00)-02-29)T(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9](?:Z|[+-][01][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])$"}
```

*Note:* Maybe the non-capturing groups have to be removed. The implementation I have used for the test, accepts it. It probably depends on the implementation.