# RegEx for validating correct ISO8601 date string

Tags: java, regex, isodate

For example: `2013-08-11T17:22:04.51+01:00`

In this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28022901/4170892) cover ISODateTime without **.51** part.

Please help to correct this regex

```regex
^(?:[1-9]\d{3}-(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])|(?:0[13-9]|1[0-2])-(?:29|30)|(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31)|(?:[1-9]\d(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:[2468][048]|[13579][26])00)-02-29)T(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d(?:Z|[+-][01]\d:[0-5]\d)$
```

to handle my format.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3788176)

Comment: Why would you use regex for something like this when you can try parsing it as a `ZonedDateTime` instead?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @Jacob G, but I should validate the value of property with javax.validation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using capturing groups, you can simply design an expression to capture anything that you wish from your input. For example [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/nrBsiU/1),

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})[A-Z]+(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).([0-9+-:]+)
```

divides your input into three capturing groups and you can simply call them using $1-$3.

You can also add any char that you may want to in `[]`.

[image]

#### RegEx Descriptive Graph

This graph shows how the expression would work and you can visualize other expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### Java Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})[A-Z]+(\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}).([0-9+-:]+)";
final String string = "2013-08-11T17:22:04.51+01:00";
final String subst = "\\1 \\2 \\3";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})[A-Z]+(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).([0-9+-:]+)/gm;
const str = `2013-08-11T17:22:04.51+01:00`;
const subst = `\nGroup 1: $1\nGroup 2: $2\nGroup 3: $3\n`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### Basic Performance Test

This JavaScript snippet shows the expression performance using a simple 1-million times `for` loop.

```js
const repeat = 1000000;
const start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 const string = '2013-08-11T17:22:04.51+01:00';
 const regex = /(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})[A-Z]+(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).([0-9+-:]+)/gm;
 var match = string.replace(regex, "\nGroup #1: $1 \n Group #2: $2 \n Group #3: $3 \n");
}

const end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```

Answer (score 4):

Regular expressions are convenient sometimes, but as a rule hard to read and (as you have experienced) hard to debug. Java has built-in parsing and validation of ISO 8601 format, and it accepts strings with and without decimals like `.51`. I understand that you are asking because you need to validate through javax.validation, which requires a regex. So only for other readers: the choice is obvious: don’t use regex here.

```
    try {
        OffsetDateTime.parse("2013-08-11T17:22:04.51+01:00");
        System.out.println("Valid ISO 8601");
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Not valid ISO 8601");
    }
```

> Valid ISO 8601

Caveat: `OffsetDateTime.parse` still doesn’t accept *all* variants of ISO 8601, but far more variants than your regular expression does.

Comment: This is, of course, the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should do the job:

```
^([\+-]?\d{4}(?!\d{2}\b))((-?)((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\3([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[01]))?|W([0-4]\d|5[0-2])(-?[1-7])?|(00[1-9]|0[1-9]\d|[12]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|6[1-6])))([T\s]((([01]\d|2[0-3])((:?)[0-5]\d)?|24\:?00)([\.,]\d+(?!:))?)?(\17[0-5]\d([\.,]\d+)?)?([zZ]|([\+-])([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)?)?)?)?$
```

ref. https://www.myintervals.com/blog/2009/05/20/iso-8601-date-validation-that-doesnt-suck/

Comment: Thanks @ibiza it is works.

Comment: What is the purpose of `[\+-]?` at the beginning? And `(?!\d{2}\b)`? ...