# checking the ISO data format is not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check if the 'date-time' string is ISO formatted  and I get the following output:

```
isIsoDate the date string is not ISO format! :  2022-04-21T09:40:01.000Z
isIsoDate converted-back date :  2022-04-21T09:40:01.000Z
isIsoDate time stamp number :  1650534001000
isIsoDate string builded back :  Thu Apr 21 2022 11:40:01 GMT+0200 (Ora legale dell’Europa centrale)
```

this is my code:

```
export function isIsoDate(dateString) {
    
        var dateParsedNum = Date.parse(dateString);
        var dateBackToString = new Date(dateParsedNum);
        var stringBuilded = "";
    
    
        stringBuilded = dateBackToString.toString()
    
    
        if ((dateBackToString.toString()) == dateString) {
            return true;
            
        } else {
           console.debug("isIsoDate() the date string is not ISO format! : ", dateString);
           console.debug("isIsoDate() converted-back date : ", dateBackToString);
           console.debug("isIsoDate() time stamp number : ", dateParsedNum);
           console.debug("isIsoDate() string builded back : ", stringBuilded);
           // throw new BadRequestException('Validation failed');
        }
    
        return(false)
    }
```

Comment: Change `dateBackToString.toString()` to `dateBackToString.toISOString()`. That being said, this won't be enough (e.g. `+00:00` is changed to `Z`).

Comment: I suppose you could replace `Z` with `+00:00` and then compare.  Or use an `if` statement and make that comparison a special case.

Comment: ``` var dateParsedNum = Date.parse(dateString);
    var dateBackToString = new Date(dateParsedNum);
    var stringBuilded = "";


    // stringBuilded = dateBackToString.toString()
    stringBuilded = dateBackToString.toISOString()

 The above is now working as expected, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it can be done with JavaScript's `Date` utilities. As Salman said in the comments, you can have [`.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) instead, but this method converts everything into UTC, whereas the ISO specification is more flexible than that.

I recommend [this StackOverFlow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28022901/6739891) that uses RegEx to validate ISO strings.