# Regex: How to include character of "if" condition

Tags: java, regex

I'm making a date extractor using regex in java. Problem is that date is 20-05-2014 and my program is extracting 0-5-14. In short, how can I get the character on which I'm checking the second character of date?

```
    int count = 0;
    String data = "HellowRoldsThisis20-05-2014. farhan_rock@gmail.comHellowRoldsThisis.farhan@gmail.com";
    String regexOfDate = "((?<=[0])[1-9]{2})|((?<=[12])[0-9])|((?<=[3])[01])\\.\\-\\_((?<=[0])[1-9])|((?<=[1])[0-2])\\.\\-\\_((?<=[2])[0-9]{4})"; \\THE PROBLEM
    String[] extractedDate = new String[1000];
    Pattern patternDate = Pattern.compile(regexOfDate);
    Matcher matcherDate = patternDate.matcher(data);

    while(matcherDate.find()){           
        System.out.println("Date "+count+"Start: "+matcherDate.start());
        System.out.println("Date "+count+"End  : "+matcherDate.end());
        extractedDate[count] = data.substring(matcherDate.start(), matcherDate.end());
        System.out.println("Date Extracted: "+extractedDate[count]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the regular expression:

```java
// (0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|[3][01])[._-](0[1-9]|1[0-2])[._-](2[0-9]{3})
"(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|[3][01])[._-](0[1-9]|1[0-2])[._-](2[0-9]{3})"
```

[image: Debuggex]

Comment: How can one draw regex?

Answer (score 0):

A single regex o match valid dates is [awful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3873172/372239).

I'd do:

```
String regexOfDate = "(?<!\\d)\\d{2}[-_.]\\d{2}[-_.]\\d{4}(?!\\d)";
```

to extract the potential date, then test if it is valid.