# Writing JS regex for YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new with JS and I need to validate a date in a form. The date field is a **regular text field**. The name of the date field called "date". How can I validate if the date is from the format of YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM with a simple regular expression in JS?

Thanks

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: There is NO `simple regular expression` that validates date-time. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/3873172/372239

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this way to validate your date in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM` format

```
   var re = /[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]) (2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]/;
var str = '2014-02-04 12:34';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```

[image]

SEE DEMO :https://www.regex101.com/r/rT6vJ4/1

Comment: It matches `0000-02-31 00:00 but doesn't take care of leap second. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second

Answer (score 4):

you can try this also :

```
var myRegExp=/^\d{4}-[0-1][0-2]-[0-3]\d\s([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d$/;
var date="2015-01-01 10:10";

if(date.match(myRegExp)){
   console.log("Good format");
}
```

Infos about the regular expression :

- " ^ " : assert position at start of the string
- " \d{x} " :  match a digit Exactly x times
- " - " : matches the character - literally
- " [range] " : match a single character present in the rang
- " \s " : match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
- " $ " : assert position at end of the string

You can test it by yourself at : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJgeeV

[ Updated following David Faber's advice ]

Comment: This `[0-1][0-2]` would allow only the following months: `00` (not valid), `01`, `02`, `10`, `11`, `12`. You need something more like this to validate the month: `(0[1-9]|1[0-2])`.

Comment: @DavidFaber thanks for the advice, i updated the regexp for months and days

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer Ben. It helps me to understand how to write regex in js, but are you sure about it? the date 2015-02-01 09:40 (which is valid date) not accepted by your regex.

Comment: Hi, i've made a mistake, this is the correcte regexp :
^\d{4}-[0-1][0-2]-[0-3]\d\s([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d$.
the post is updated

Comment: It matches `0000-00-00 00:00` but doesn't take care of leap second. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second

Answer (score 1):

When I googled it, there are some great examples such as [Date Form Validation](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/validate-date/)