# Using regex to match date format in yyyymmdd

Tags: regex, date, nsregularexpression, leap-year

The regex should match valid dates in a string in the format `YYYYMMDD`. For example, `aaa_20150327_bbb` should be matched but `aaa_20150229_bbb` not because 2015 is not a leap year.

Only year from *2000* to *2099* need to be considered.

Comment: It's not going to be possible to exclude `2/29` if it's not a leap year with regex. At least not in a sane way. You'll have to parse that out after the fact. Is there a problem with `\d{8}` ? Or at least `20\d{2}[01]\d[0123]\d`?

Comment: @JoeWang What language are you using? C++ has the functionality to do this built-in, without the use of a regex

Comment: ahh... how re can achieve this... just do 5 min research about what re is will let you be able to rule this possibility out.

Comment: This is not an appropriate problem for RegEx. Fortunately there are good libraries for dealing with dates. Extract the string and then use a date parsing library to work with it as a date.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3873172/372239

Answer (score 28):

## Total madness (years 0-9999)

The following one (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224/regular-expression-to-match-valid-dates) answer) works for years between 0 and 9999.

```
(?<!\d)(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})(?:(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])31)|(?:(?:0[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(?:29|30)))|(?:(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))0229)|(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8]))(?!\d)
```

(check the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nM7cT1/4))

---

## Total madness *simplified* (years 2000-2099)

If you want you can simplify it to only work for years between 2000 and 2099.

```
(?<!\d)(?:(?:20\d{2})(?:(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])31)|(?:(?:0[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(?:29|30)))|(?:(?:20(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))0229)|(?:20\d{2})(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8]))(?!\d)
```

But as you can see it's not really more simple.

(check the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pI3cI5/5))

---

## The sane way (years *)

To keep your sanity you should stick to a very simple regex and then validate it using code.

```
(20\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})
```

(check the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vS3fC8/3))

Comment: + for the "sane" way! I'd be tempted to perform a sanity test in regex, and then (where required) use a different method to navigate and calendar *weirdness*.

Comment: Why not `(20\d{6})` for the last one?

Comment: @IanS Why not? Because I want three separate capturing groups so that I can use the separate matches for year, month, and day when creating a date object.  Example: `new Date(match[1], match[2] - 1, match[3])`

Comment: Warning: this is not ensuring there are 8 digits in the date. If you input 2000123 it will match as Dec 3rd, even if it was supposed to be Dec 31st and the number 1 is missing.

Answer (score 3):

**My way (not the sane way)**

```
(((\d{4})(0[13578]|10|12)(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))|((\d{4})(0[469]|11)(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30))|((\d{4})(02)(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]))|([0-9][0-9][02468]40229)|([0-9][0-9][02468]80229)|([0-9][0-9][13579]20229)|([0-9][0-9][13579]60229)|([0-9][0-9][02468]00229))
```

**With vb.net** (more easy to understand, I think so)

```
    Dim meses31 As String = "((\d{4})(0[13578]|10|12)(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))"
    Dim meses30 As String = "((\d{4})(0[469]|11)(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30))"
    Dim febrero28 As String = "((\d{4})(02)(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]))"
    Dim febrero29 As String = "([0-9][0-9][02468]40229)|([0-9][0-9][02468]80229)|([0-9][0-9][13579]20229)|([0-9][0-9][13579]60229)|([0-9][0-9][02468]00229)"

    Dim patternFecha As String = String.Concat("(", meses31, "|", meses30, "|", febrero28, "|", febrero29, ")")
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked best for me:

```
\\d{4}(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])
```

You can use it like this, for example:

```
import re
date_matched = re.search(r"\d{4}(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])", yourstringhere)
date_matched = None if date_matched is None else date_matched[0]
```

Example:

1. "test20001231test" -> 20001231
2. "20001231" -> 20001231
3. "2000123" -> No match
4. "200012311" -> 20001231
5. "20001232" -> No match

Limitations:

- Works for years 0000-9999, months 01-12, and days 01-31
- Doesn't validate days on months that have 30 or less days, like 20000229 (Feb 29th).

Reference: https://riptutorial.com/r/example/28566/validate-a-date-in-a--yyyymmdd--format