# C++ boost regex date error

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I am quite new to boost regex library.The following sample code is used to check if the entered date is following the `YYYY-MM-DD` format.However,there seems to be an error in the regex. It always return's`false`. 
*

> - I am running the console application on windows.

*
the regex was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307768/using-regex-to-match-date-format-in-yyyymmdd)

```
bool regexValidate(string teststring)
{
boost::regex ex("^(20\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})");
if (boost::regex_match(teststring, ex)) {
    cout << "true";
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
}
 int main()
{


string  teststr = "2016-05-15";


cout << teststr << " is ";
if (regexValidate( teststr)) {
    cout << " valid!" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << " invalid!" << endl;
}

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there; just add hyphens to your regex:

```
"^(20\\d{2})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})"
```

BTW, this won't parse dates before 2000 or after 2099.  And there's no explicit end-of-string ($) at the end.  Something more like:

```
"^(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})$"
```

...I think should make you good anywhere in recent centuries ;-)

Comment: Thanks! works fine  shall include  end-of-string ($)