# SAS - extract 8-digit pattern with regex / prxmatch

Tags: regex, sas

What's the best way of extracting a date-stamp with the format `yyyymmdd` from an existing string in SAS?

From what I read, the easiest way seems to be using regular expressions withing the `prxmatch` function to replace everything **but** the pattern.

- Let's assume that the only 8-digit pattern in the string will be my date, so a `[0-9]{8}` pattern is sufficient.

Here is what i have for replacing 8-digit patterns with the string `empty` (for readability):

```
data b(keep=have want);

    /* HAVE */
   have = '&libroot_hr./import/sxh3j900/20190702_SXH3J900_DWH_Adresse.txt';
   regexp = 's/[0-9]{8}/empty/';
   times  = -1;  /* -1: replace all occurences */

    /* WANT */
   want = prxchange(regexp, times, have);

   /* Result
       '&libroot_hr./import/sxh3j900/empty_SXH3J900_DWH_Adresse.txt'
   */

run;
```

How can I change this, so it replaces everything **but** any 9-digit patterns with the string `empty`?

Comment: Can the strings have more than one string of 8 digits? Do the strings of 8 digits need to be independent of other digits? Or do you want to match 8 digits that are part of a longer string of digits?

Comment: Let's assume that  the only 8-digit pattern in the string will be my date. The date-string will be surrounded by non-digit characters. There will be other numbers (`3` and `900` in my example), but no other strings of 8 or more consecutive numbers. Therefore `[0-9]{8}`  should be sufficient to locate my string (but i need the inverse and locate everything *but* said string)

Comment: Then why not just pull out the date string and write it back to the variable?

Comment: You mean like the solution from **Aurieli**? I am not quite sure yet when to use which prx-function... will test it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data b(keep=have want);
   have='&libroot_hr./import/sxh3j900/20190702_SXH3J900_DWH_Adresse.txt';
   re = prxparse("/(\d{8})/"); 
   if prxmatch(re,have) then do;
      want = prxposn(re,0,have);
   end;
run;
```

If u want just extract the first 8-digits.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307768/using-regex-to-match-date-format-in-yyyymmdd) the regexp to **yyyymmdd** format.

Comment: thanks for your answer. will test it - looks promising on the first test... i will mark an answer as soon as i have it tested :)

Comment: @MartinDreher I advise you to use regexp: "/((19\d{2})|(2\d{3}))(\d{2})(\d{2})/", i think its better then "/(\d{8})/" :)

Comment: naturally, i only used "/(\d{8})/" for simpler code while trying to understand your solution. works like a charm btw. thanks mate!