# Verify date with regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

date format is 2015/04/25
I am trying

```
^\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}$
```

And its working fine, But i want to validate that the month should b less then 12 and date less then 31

I had tried this

```
^\d{4}\/(\d{2}\<[12])\/\d{2}$
```

But it is not working.

PS: I am very noob in regular expressions.

Comment: `explode()` with `checkdate()` would be more reliable: http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php. Note that for example February 30 does not exist.

Comment: Yeah, But i also want to validate at client side  through html5 pattern.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/3873172/372239

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
^\d{4}\/(0\d|1[0-2])\/([0-2]\d|3[01])$
```

Explanation:

- `\d{4}` any four digits
- `(0\d|1[0-2])` 0(any digit) or 1(0 to 2) i.e `00 to 09` or `10-12`
- `([0-2]\d|3[01])` (0 to 2)(any digit) or 3(0 or 1) i.e `00 to 29` or `30 or 31`

**Edit1:** If you want to match from `01-12` only for months and `01-31` only for day (without `00`) you can use :

```
^\d{4}\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])$
```

**Edit2:** If you want strict validation of dates use `explode` and `checkdate`.. as suggested by @Wayne.. since it also includes validation of leap years.

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iX2fB9/4)

Comment: This will still allow for false positives, such as 2015/02/31

Comment: @kingkero yes.. regex is for matching patterns only.. if I want to have validation rules separately for every month i would use `explode` and `checkdate` .. since it also considers leap year validation.. :)

Comment: Yes, my comment was aimed at OP

Comment: Thank @karthikmanchala , Yeah kignkero You are right, But i can handle this on server side :)

Answer (score 1):

As jeroen pointed out above, the best solution would be to use a combination of the functions explode and checkdate. A regex isn't going to catch dates that never occurred.

```
$exploded = explode("/", $date);
if(checkdate($exploded[1], $exploded[2], $exploded[0])){
   //Valid date.
}
```

PS, you might also want to check the number of elements in the $exploded array, seeing as you're expecting three strings.

Answer (score 1):

here is extended version of the same principle shown by used @karthik manchala

```
^((\d{4}\/(0[469]|11)\/(0[1-9]|1\d|30))|(\d{4}\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/([0-2]\d|3[01]))|(\d{4}\/(02)\/(0[1-9]|[12]\d)))$
```

it will filter as well 30 vs 31 and everything above 29 for february. It will not recognise when to use 28 and 29 in february though.

If you want to capture leap year you can do it easily if it is recent date or date in near future as it is divisible by 4, you can capture 2000, 2004, 2008, 2012 etc. but the rule is not consistent.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/3873172/372239 it deals with leap years