# Regex to match ddmmyy with leap year as well?

Tags: regex

I have made a regex, which matches all months perfectly. Well, perfectly as far as I can see. It matches 01-end of each month, and I cannot seem to generate a false month, unless I enter something like the 32nd of March, which is an invalid date.

Anyway, what I need to do is match the last `yy` of the regex. If `yy` ends in a number that can be divided by 4, such as 20, 24, 16, etc, it should ONLY make 2902yy valid. Since I am not checking `yyyy`, I cannot check if the year is 1900 or 2000, which both ends in `00`. Here you can see my current regex:

```
(((((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30)|31)(0[13789]|(10|12)))|(((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30))(0[34569]|11))|(((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-7])|(28|29))02))(0?[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]){2})
```

Check out my regex and matches here: http://regexr.com/3buc2

Should not match:
`290291` because there is no leap year ending in `xx91`

Should match:
`290292` because there is a leap year in 1992/1892/1792

Get what I mean? How can I possibly do that to my regex? Also, can my regex be optimized? `\d` instead of `[0-9]` could be done, but it's slower because it matches numbers in different encodings too, and I only need to match 0-9.

Comment: I doubt... regular expression follows the process and limitation of finite automaton, should not be capable to do the leap year calculation (except hard code a year range for matching).

Comment: Regex is not the best tool to validate dates. But have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3873172/372239

Comment: What programming language are you using for this task? (I guess) every language has got some library for parsing/validating DateTime.

Comment: Why on earth would you use regex for this?!

Comment: To everyone: This is a for a school project. I am simply expanding it :) I know it is possible to do the leap year calculation if you have a whole year as yyyy. It's simply checking the last two digits in this case. But I assume it's not possible, because 04 would be legit, 08 would as well, but 02 would as well, just not 22 or 42 for instance.

Comment: Why would `02` be legit?

Comment: @hjpotter92: Ah, I wrote that on my phone. Meant to say 12 is legit, but not 22, 42 etc. Numbers divided by 4 basically. So you can't do [0-9][48] for instance. I think. Just throwing it out there without thinking.

Comment: For the last 2 digits: `[02468][048]|[13579][26]` <- leap years

Comment: @hjpotter92 Yep I just made that as well and it matches yours. Exactly the same, lol. So if that is true, it should make 2902XX be true as well. Or match, whatever.

Comment: You need to decide which century you are working on, because the results are different in different centuries.  Does your regex attempt to target the 1900s or the 2000s?

Comment: @tripleee How does that affect it? Let's assume we're working in 1900 and 2000. There is probably NOT someone alive born the 29th of February 1600 or 1900, which is 290200 (because that date never happened). But 290200 is also the same date in 2000. Because I want all centuries to work, the 1600/1900 should match as well, even though it's not possible (nobody is 400 years old), but let's assume it anyway.

Comment: 290200 existed in 2000, but not in 1900.

Comment: One of your test cases is wrong.  1994 was not a leap year and 2094 will not be a leap year. You might want 96 for the year instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regular expressions for this is madness, or at least borderline.  But here is a sketch at a solution.

Days 00 through 28 should always be okay.

Day 30 should be okay if the month is not 02.

Day 31 should be okay if the month is not 02, 04, 06, 09, or 11.

Day 29 should be okay if the month is not 02 or the year is a leap year.

Since you only have two digits for the year, we assume you only want to operate in the current century.  The leap years are the years which are divisible by 4. (There are some complications, but they do not apply in this century, because 2000 is evenly divisible by 400 as well as by 100.)

So we can enumerate the years which are leap years: 00, 04, 08, 12, 16, 20, ...

If the first digit in the two-digit year is an even number, then the year is a leap year if the second digit is 0, 4, or 8.

If the first digit is odd, the year is a leap year if the second digit is 2 or 6.

```
([01][0-9]|2[0-8])(0[0-9]|1[0-2])[0-9][0-9]|
30(0[013-9]|1[0-2])[0-9][0-9]|
31(0[13578]|1[02])[0-9][0-9]|
29((0[013-9]|1[0-2])[0-9][0-9]|02([0246][048]|[13579][26]))
```

Note that you will need a different regex for the years 1900-1999 because the leap years were different then (in particular, 1900 was not a leap year, because it is not divisible by 400.)

Comment: That is correct. All you said is correct. I did most of it here: http://regexr.com/3bud9 - This matches the dates, but adding the "if `[02468][048]|[13579][26]` is the year, make 2902XX match as well" to my regex is where I am having an issue.

Comment: Well.. shoot. I nailed it myself, but DAMN it's long compared to yours: `((((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30)|31)(0[13789]|(10|12)))|(((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30))(0[34569]|11)))(0?[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]){2}|((((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-7])|28)02)(0?[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]){2})|((((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-7])|29)02)([02468][048]|[13579][26]))` - It works though: http://regexr.com/3budl - Yours works as well.. but it's like half as long lol. EDIT: Mine is this long, because I had to include the 00-99 to each, which basically is [0-9][0-9].. yeah. I am not a pro at regex at all, but thanks!

Comment: Yeah definitely will do both. Just looking at yours and comparing it to mine, so I can improve my regular expression skills. Does my question deserve a downvote though? Haha